# How to pass props in the component to FlatList renderItem

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Function as a prop in my component and I have to pass this Function Prop to another Component in the renderItem in FlastList. How to do that? Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'native-base';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import AddPlayers from '../AddPlayers/AddPlayers';
import League from '../League/League';
export default class InviteLeagues extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    invitedLeagues: PropTypes.Array,
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    InvitedLeaguesList: PropTypes.Array,
    onPress: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    InvitedLeaguesList: [
      { name: 'Howdy', createdBy: 'email1@gamil.com', status: 'Join' },
      { name: 'Lorem', createdBy: 'email@gmail.com', status: 'Join' }
    ]
  };

  renderLeague(item) {
    return <League invitedLeague={item} />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View {...this.props}>
        <AddPlayers
          label={this.props.label}
          labelStyle={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}
        />
        <FlatList
          numColumns={1}
          data={this.props.InvitedLeaguesList}
          renderItem={this.renderLeague}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I have to pass `onPress` (Function Prop) to `League` Component

I tried like this

```
 <FlatList
          numColumns={1}
          data={this.props.InvitedLeaguesList}
          renderItem={this.renderLeague}
          extraData={this.props}
        />

renderLeague(item) {
    return <League invitedLeague={item} onPress={this.props.onPress} />;
  }
```

Comment: Change `renderLeague() {}` to `renderLeague = () => {}` and it should work.

Comment: You are passing the function prop correctly you just need to call this.props.onPress() from the League component and change the function definition of renderLeague() {} to renderLeague = () => {}  and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**This way is working for me**

```
<FlatList
     numColumns={1}
     data={this.props.InvitedLeaguesList}
     renderItem={({ item }) => <League invitedLeague={item} onPress={this.props.onPress} />}
     extraData={this.props}
 />
```

[image]

Comment: Able to get onPress props in <League /> Component

Comment: And use it like this with Props Type Parameters:
`type LeagueProps = {
  item:any;
  onPress:any;
}; function League({ item, navigation }: LeagueProps){...}`

Answer (score 27):

you can pass props as a parameter to the function that render items of flat list as below:

```
<FlatList
     numColumns={1}
     data={this.props.InvitedLeaguesList}
     renderItem={(item) => this.renderLeague(item, this.props)}
/>
```

and you can use this parameter in the `renderLeague` function:

```
renderLeague({item}, props) {
   ...
}
```

that props variable include all parameter of props as you can use `this.props` in another place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to make a `callBack` function, 
if so, please do the following.

```
renderLeague(item) {
    return <League invitedLeague={item} onPress={this._callBack.bind(this)} />;
}


//callback function
_callBack(data) {
   // your code here...
}
```

From your component `League`

call the function like the following,

```
this.props.onPress(datas);
```

Comment: You should always `bind` in the constructor.